# Django queryset question

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255) 
    price =  models.FloatField('Price', blank=True)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)    
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

How do I get Ticket.price * CartItem.Quantity where event = event

Comment: If you look at at `Ticket`, it has a `cartitem_set` attribute which can provide a list of all `CartItems` which refer to the ticket.  Since there may be more than one, there's no simple ticket price times quantity.  There could be multiple quantities.

Comment: @Nai did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add error checking but you could do something like this logic-wise:

```
total = 0
cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(ticket__event=event) # assuming there are multiple cart items per event
for cart_item in cart_items:
    new_total = cart_item.ticket.price * cart_item.quantity
    total = total + new_total
```

That should give you total revenue for an event.